# QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running (for itself it works)

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pyqt5

I have a program that I have programmed in several steps (each page by itself) and now I have problems assembling them.
The individual Windows have worked for themselves but together the worker of Mainwindow does not work properly. Since I have little idea of ​​PyQt, it may be that the error is also quite obvious.

Update: Now the program works but the pictures only start to load when a button is pressed (at the moment I deleted the other thread). Now my question is how can I do this automatically.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
import time
import os
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

path = "C:/Users/benni/Desktop/"  
folder_name = "exit_folder_test"  
name_list = "used_names.txt"
source = "test"
extension = "jpg"

if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, name_list)):
    used_names = open(path + name_list, "w+")
    used_names.close()
    names =[]
else:
    used_names = open(path + name_list, "r")
    names = used_names.readlines() 
    used_names.close()
    print(names)

#####################################################################################

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    switch_window = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(widget)
        rows, cols = 2, 3
        self._labels = []
        global image_width, image_height, number, pictures
        image_width, image_height, number = 600, 400, 0
        pictures = []

        for row in range(rows):
            for col in range(cols):
                label = QtWidgets.QLabel(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
                label.setFixedSize(image_width, image_height)
                grid_layout.addWidget(label, row, col)
                self._labels.append(label)


        self.ComboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.ComboBox, 3, 2, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.ComboBox.setFixedSize(125,25)

        self.refresh_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("update")  # update button (this one I want to remove)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.refresh_button, 3, 1)
        self.refresh_button.setFixedSize(125,25)
        self.refresh_button.clicked[bool].connect(self.update)

        self.print_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("print")  # print button
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.print_button, 3, 3)
        self.print_button.setFixedSize(75,25)
        self.print_button.clicked[bool].connect(self.print)
        self.resize(1920, 1080)



    def update(self):               
        global number, pictures
        for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(path, source)):       # add all files with ".jpg" to the list pictures
            if file.endswith(".{}".format(extension)):
                pictures.append(file)
        if len(pictures) > 0:
            for picture_name in pictures:
                number += 1
                if 0 < number < 7:
                    time.sleep(1)  # wait until the picture is transferred
                    picture_new_name = "image{}.{}".format(number, extension)
                    os.rename(
                        os.path.join(path, source, picture_name),
                        os.path.join(path, folder_name, picture_new_name),
                    )  # renames all the given pictures and transfer them in a new folder  
                    print(number)
                    time.sleep(0.2)
                    label = self._labels[number-1]
                    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(os.path.join(path, folder_name, "image{}.{}".format(number, extension))).scaled(image_width, image_height)
                    label.setPixmap(pixmap)
                    self.ComboBox.addItem("image{}.{}".format(number, extension))
            del pictures[:]



    def print(self):
        print("test")
        self.switch_window.emit()

###########################################################################################################

class WindowTwo(QtWidgets.QWidget):   

    switch_window = QtCore.pyqtSignal()       

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Window Two')

        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        self.finish_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('finish')                   
        self.finish_button.clicked.connect(self.finished)                  
        self.finish_button.setFixedSize(75,23)
        layout.addWidget(self.finish_button, 3,3)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.resize(1920, 1080)

    def finished(self):                              
        self.switch_window.emit()    # reset 

###########################################################################################################

class Login(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    switch_window = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Fotobox')
        self.resize(1920,1080)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        self.Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('next')        
        self.Button.setFixedSize(85,30)
        layout.addWidget(self.Button, 3, 3)
        self.Button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)                           

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("name: ")
        self.label.setFixedSize(120,51)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 1)            

        self.error_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("")         
        self.error_label.setFixedSize(120,51)
        layout.addWidget(self.error_label, 2,2)

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()            
        self.lineEdit.setFixedSize(260,31)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit,  1, 2)       
        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.issue_test)                

        self.setLayout(layout)



    def issue_test(self):                    
        self.issue = False                       
        name = self.lineEdit.text()         
        for i in names:               
            if name == i or name+"\n" == i:                     
                self.error_label.setText("error")
                self.issue = True
        if self.issue == False:              
            self.issue = False
            self.error_label.setText("")

    def on_click(self):                     
        global folder_name                         
        name = self.lineEdit.text()
        if  name == "":                  
            self.error_label.setText("error")
            self.issue = True

        if self.issue == False:                    
            folder_name = name
            os.mkdir(path + folder_name)           
            names.append(folder_name)             

            used_names = open(path + name_list, "a")
            used_names.write(name + "\n")
            used_names.close()

            self.switch_window.emit()              # switch to the mainwindow

######################################################################################################################################################

class Controller:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def show_login(self):
        self.login = Login()
        try: self.window_two.close()
        except:
            print("first time")
        self.login.switch_window.connect(self.show_main)
        self.login.show()

    def show_main(self):
        self.window = MainWindow()
        self.window.switch_window.connect(self.show_window_two)
        self.login.close()
        self.window.show()


    def show_window_two(self):
        self.window_two = WindowTwo()
        self.window.close()
        self.window_two.switch_window.connect(self.show_login)
        self.window_two.show()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    controller = Controller()
    controller.show_login()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: change `thread` to `self.thread`

Comment: the error disappears but no picture is loading and also no number is printed (should be printed after the search-function has found a new image).
I changed the first 5 lines of the MainWindow-class. Could this cause the problem?